# How would I loop through elements Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a website for which I want to download excel files. (https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/eenzaamheid.html)

First I want to click on the region and then perform the download. This I have working.

```
wijk_keuze = WebDriverWait(driver2nd,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='path']")))
wijk_keuze.click()
download = WebDriverWait(driver2nd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @aria-label='View export menu']//*[name()='rect']")))  
download.click()
WebDriverWait(download, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-menu']//*[contains(text(),'XLS downloaden')]"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
```

above code selects the first region in the parent element and then downloads the excel.
What I want to do is loop through each element in the parent element. How would I go about doing so?

The parent element looks as follows:

```
<g transform="transform(0,0), scale(1,1)" animator="1">
```

my entire code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#defining URL
url='https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/eenzaamheid.html'

#defining driver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r'./phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized");
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path = r'./chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

# Gemeentes 

Detail_keuze = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("detail"))
options = Detail_keuze.options
Indicator_keuze = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("indicator"))
indicator_options = Indicator_keuze.options


for index in range(0, len(indicator_options) ):
    #defining URL
    url='https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/eenzaamheid.html'

    #defining driver
    driver2nd = webdriver.PhantomJS(r'./phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs')
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized");
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": r"MY_PATH",
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": True
        })
    driver2nd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path = r'./chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
    driver2nd.get(url)

    # Gemeentes 
    Detail_keuze = Select(driver2nd.find_element_by_id("detail"))
    options = Detail_keuze.options
    Indicator_keuze = Select(driver2nd.find_element_by_id("indicator"))
    indicator_options = Indicator_keuze.options
    time.sleep(1)

    Indicator_keuze.select_by_index(index)
    wijk_keuze = WebDriverWait(driver2nd,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='path']")))
    wijk_keuze.click()

    download = WebDriverWait(driver2nd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @aria-label='View export menu']//*[name()='rect']")))  
    download.click()
    WebDriverWait(download, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-menu']//*[contains(text(),'XLS downloaden')]"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
######## HERE I WANT TO LOOP THROUGH EACH AND EVERY REGION
    driver2nd.close()
```

As you can see I also want to loop through eachh and every indicator. This works. Now I want to add a loop through each and every region. I have it working so that I can click on the first region.

Comment: I am not able to run your code. I guess you can select all the elements instead of selecting one and then use comprehension lists in python to apply a particular functionality to every element on this list.

Comment: I edited my question and added my entire code, hope this helps in finding a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to click on the options. You can get the details by changing the url `'https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/{indicator}?detail={detail}'`
Just add the logic for downloading it.

Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import product

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())#, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/eenzaamheid.html')
time.sleep(5)
soup  = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
ind = soup.find('select', attrs = {'name': 'indicator'} )
indicators = [i['value'] for i in ind.findAll('option')]

det = soup.find('select', attrs = {'name': 'detail'})
details = [i['value'] for i in det.findAll('option')]
for detail, indicator in list(product(details, indicators)):
    print(indicator, detail)
    new_url = f'https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/{indicator}?detail={detail}'
    driver.get(new_url)
   # Write code for downloading it
```